# Path::read_dir and Windows

Tags: windows, rust

This is a simple test app to display the contents of a directory:

```
fn main() {
    let mut p = PathBuf::from(r"c:");
    println!("drive 1: {}", p.to_str().unwrap());
    p.push(std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR.to_string());
    println!("drive 2: {}", p.to_str().unwrap());
    p.push(r"*.*");
    println!("drive 3: {}", p.to_str().unwrap());

    println!("root: {}", p.to_str().unwrap());
    match fs::read_dir(p) {
        Ok(x) => {
            for path in x {
                println!("path: {:?}", path);
            }
        }
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Error: {}", why);
        }
    };
}
```

The output is:

```
drive 1: c:  
drive 2: c:\  
drive 3: c:\\*.*  
walk_dir: root: c:\\*.*  
Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)
```

The `println!`s are to follow the progressing of my path. Please forgive the variable names as I brought the `match` statement in from a function to make it easier to read.

When I cut and paste the final path, `c:\*.*`, into a command prompt with `dir`, it works as expected.

I know it's not the content of the string, rather what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

This was a misunderstanding of the input parameters into `read_dir`.

I was under the assumption that `read_dir` wanted a string that would be similar to a Windows dir command-line or UNIX/Linux `ls` command.  That is, I gave it `c:\\*.*` expecting all of the files in the `c:` drive root directory.

Instead, `read_dir` wants only the root directory with no file specification.  The sorting/filtering will happen later.

The input that worked was simply `C:\\.`

Answer (score 1):

`c:\*.*` is not a path, it is a glob pattern. As you found out yourself `read_dir` expects a path, so in your case it expects `c:\`. If you really need a glob pattern (eg. `c:\*.txt`), you will need to filter the output of `read_dir` yourself, or you can use the [`glob`](https://crates.io/crates/glob) crate.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `PathBuf::from(r"c:")` with `PathBuf::from(r"c:\")` and/or `p.push(r"*.*");` with `p.push(r"\*.*");`?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push:

> On Windows:
>
> - if `path` has a root but no prefix (e.g., `\windows`), it replaces everything except for the prefix (if any) of `self`.
> - if `path` has a prefix but no root, it replaces `self`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/enum.Prefix.html:

> Windows path prefixes, e.g., C: or \server\share.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The problem is not the final string (the path is indeed "C:\\*.*".  The "C:\\*.*" is what is passed into Path::read_dir in the variable p (I believe).  Could it be something else, or better said, what else could it be.  If I'm missing your point above, I'm sorry.